# Safest DB connection in c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection

I'm refactoring some old code as we're periodically having connection pool issues on a clients site.

While some code has wrapped DB connections in try/catch blocks I'll be using the `using(){}` thing (is there a proper term for this?)

So I'd like some clarification on how to use it in our situation to make as few changes as possible.

What we currently have is (mostly) something like this:

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

try
{
  // DB stuff here
}
finally
{
  sqlCmd.Dispose();
  sqlConn.Dispose();
}
```

Some connections aren't wrapped up at all.

So, I'm thinking of changing it to this:

```
using (SqlConnection ThisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
  using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
  {
    sqlCmd.Connection = ThisConnection;
    // DB stuff here
  }
}
```

I've tried this and it works. But I know there's a difference between something working and something working well :)

So, a few questions:

1. If the SqlConnection is assigned to SqlCommand.Connection and I only wrap up the SqlCommand in a using, will the connection be closed and disposed then the SqlCommand is?
2. If not, is the above code ok? Or should the SqlCommand using be before the SqlConnection or does it not matter?
3. When the object is disposed at the end of the using is this absolutely guaranteed to close the DB connection?

All feedback greatly appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you dispose your connection, you need dispose your command, calling Dispose on it will supress the call to the finalizer. `Add using command after using conenction`
2. Don't set your command before connection
3. Yes, because you close your not managed object , who is coonnection

Remark : using bloc is preferred that try catch finally for basic need without custom treatment in catch bloc

msdn sample link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx
this article don't treat using command but speak about connection

Comment: Happy to help you Jag

Comment: One more thing. Let's say I have `using (SqlCommand)` and inside it `SqlCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection(etc)`. When the SqlCommand is disposed, will it also dispose and close the `SqlCommand.Connection`? Or do I have to explicitly close/dispose the command separately?

Comment: when you create your command you pass connection in parameter, but command is first to disposed, after this step, dispose connection, with this behavior for example you can execute lot of command without rebuild connection object

Answer (score 1):

The `using` approach is preferable; much harder to get it wrong and leave scenarios where objects can escape without being disposed. Unless you have a **very specific reason**, it should be your default. You can reduce the nesting, though:

```
using (SqlConnection ThisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    sqlCmd.Connection = ThisConnection;
    // DB stuff here
}
```

> When the object is disposed at the end of the using is this absolutely guaranteed to close the DB connection?

It will *dispose* it; the *underlying* connection (via any of these approaches) will usually still be pooled, though.

Of course, I also submit that the easiest way to do this is to *use less code* - less to get wrong. For example, I'd be **very** tempted to use "dapper", which avoids the need to mess with the commands, readers, parameter collections, etc:

```
int id = 123;
string name = "abc";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Execute("Some TSQL", new { id, name });
}
```

Comment: One of the reasons I asked this question was because I saw an answer on SO that says you don't need to Close your connection if it's disposed as part of a using statement - Aghilas Yakoub in his answer says the same thing... I'm thinking I'll explicitly close it before the end of the SqlCommand using.

Comment: @Jag that is correct; you don't need to; now, you *could* add it before the end of the `using` block, but a: it is redundant, and b: if it **wasn't** redundant, I'd be concerned that you are only doing it on the happy path (not the failure path). Basically, I wouldn't add it.

Comment: Thanks. As for dapper, that's an ORM isn't it? Unfortunately this is an old site that we want to quickly tidy up - though I'm pushing for a rewrite :)

Comment: @Jag no, it is a micro-ORM that requires no re-work, re-modelling, special classes, attributes, or anything like that; it just *makes SQL easier*. It'll also do fast binding to objects if you want, but using the simplest thing that could possible work: assume the columns will match the properties. It is also intentionally designed to be low friction, so you can use it for as much or as little data-access as you like

Comment: Thanks for that. Definitely going to add it to my "check it out" list :) cheers